# Vuex mutations updating an object with dynamic property names from async/await action

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

So I'm trying to get Nuxt to query my GQL API for the site menus. I'm doing this via the `nuxtServerInit` function in my `index.js` store module.

Like so:

```
menuLocations = ["MAIN_MENU", "WORK_MENU"]
store.dispatch("menus/QUERY_MENUS", menuLocations)
```

Which calls my `QUERY_MENUS` action from my `menus.js` store module. The code for that is this:

```
// Define State defaults
export const state = () => ({
    locations: {}
})

// Define mutations
export const mutations = {
    SET_MENU(state, data) {
        //Vue.set(state.locations, data.location, data.items)
        //state.locations = { ...state.locations, [data.location]: data.items }
    }
}

// Define actions
export const actions = {
    async QUERY_MENUS({ commit }, menuLocations) {
        let client = this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient

        // Get each menu from server
        for (const location of menuLocations) {
            const query = await client.query({
                query: MenuByLocation,
                variables: {
                    location: location
                }
            })

            // Commit menu to store
            commit("SET_MENU", {
                location: _camelCase(location),
                items: _get(query, "data.menuItems.nodes", {})
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the both the commented out lines in `SET_MENU` don't work reliably (when un-commented), sometimes they work, sometimes they don't. I'm guessing it has to do with Nuxt and SSR, or perhaps I'm doing my async/await stuff wrong?

**CODE SANDBOX HERE:**

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3yjz2wm6y?fontsize=14

Preview: https://j3yjz2wm6y.sse.codesandbox.io/

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: too vague . How exactly it dont work? Please create a reproduction on codesandbox

Comment: The code looks to be well crafted...  Is `_get` async? That looks to be needing an await...

Comment: @Aldarund sorry about that, I thought it would have been something simple like my async/await syntax. I added the codesandbox link for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In provided sandbox there two errors:

1) There no await for dispatch in nuxtServerInit

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(store, context) {
    let menuLocations = ["MAIN_MENU", "OUR_WORK_MENU"];
    await store.dispatch("menus/QUERY_MENUS", menuLocations);
  }
};
```

2) In computed property a state reference is missed

```
  return _get(this, "$store.state.menus.locations.mainMenu", false);
```

Here fixed CBS -> https://codesandbox.io/s/rrrv17oq8m

Comment: Thanks @Alarund! It was that async nuxtServerInit() that got me!